# Does converting an image count as executing it

Tags: php, security, image, image-processing

I'm talking about user uploaded images. These images might be unsafe and may even contain scripts and such. I was told that as long as I don't execute the image, I should be fine. What exactly counts as executing an image? If the user uploads a .png and I need to convert it to .jpg first before displaying it, does this conversion count as executing the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you e.g. use some library to work with the library, then the only way for that to be a security risk is an issue with the library itself. E.g. if there is a buffer overflow security issue in the library, a mere process of reading the image could potentially make it execute the code conveniently hidden in the image (i.e. image would not be the image anymore, it will be turned into code).

If you use standard libraries, chances for such security holes are rather slim. Not zero, though, but I guess you would have to live either with that or not looking at any digital picture in your life again.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the tool used to convert the image isn't vulnerable to any exploits, the act of converting it does not involve executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can trust the image conversion process if you like, but as others have said, the risk exists that simply processing the data could leave you vulnerable.  You can take other steps to isolate the image processing step if it is critical.

You could put that step on a separate machine, so that a compromise doesn't put the malicious code on the server communicating with the public.  You could  also run that process as another user, so that an exploit would have to escalate privileges in order to compromise your service.